# How can I use apcu functions apc_store(), apc_fetch() in PHPNG / PHP7?

Tags: php, apc

I have installed phpng with instructions from https://wiki.php.net/phpng

I've only gotten it to work with php-fpm. How can I make php-fpm use apcu?

Does anyone know? Is there a configuration option under ./configure --enable-fpm ... enable-apcu or similar???

php-fpm does not seem to recognize /etc/php.ini or /etc/php.d/apcu.so file

Error when linked to is below:

```
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/tmp/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20140815/apcu.so' - /tmp/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20140815/apcu.so: undefined symbol: zval_used_for_init in Unknown on line 0
```

Answer (score 1):

As the APCu author says: "APCu is not yet prepared for PHP7." So you'll need to disable that extension until it's compatible.

https://github.com/krakjoe/apcu/issues/78